# How to set global datetime format for javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

I have a several MVC pages and I have second thing for them in my web.config:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

(I need all my data to be dd/mm/yy)

It works for datetime displaying on .cshtml first time **BUT** the issue is:

I have a datepicker and several date changes with jquery.
**All of them working with mm/dd/yyyy format**. As a result, I am working with incorrect dates.

For example: In my database I have date "2014-12-05" which means 5 december 2014, but datapicker and other understand it as 12 May  (ckecked with new Date(DateValue)).

I have several date comparising (in client side validation) and because of this issue, everything works wrong.

How can I change global datetime format for each javascript I have?

Comment: Use Moment.js. If you're using a lot of third-party things there is no fast-n-easy solution.

Comment: Have you specified the date format in the datepicker plugin?

Comment: You can try setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` in `Global.asax`.

Comment: Date formatting is a pain in native JS, use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) or [DateJS](http://datejs.com) instead

Comment: Moment.js?    About datepicker format - yep. I set  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' for it, but not only it doesn't done anything, I told already that this issue exist for the whole javascript

Comment: How this Moment.js will work with model? I mean, I change field values and am sending them. Doest it convert them properly on another trick will be needed? How it will work with datepicker?